# Cross Domain Ajax Login (Same server)

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I have 2 applications. App1 is some old selfmade php project, not using Zend. And App2 is a little Zend application.

http://test.pmueller.dev.xiag.ch/ This is just for tests. In this case, it represents App1.

If you click show at newsletter 313, you will logged in and see the newsletter. This is a normal cross domain post call. Login was made in the background. Copy paste that url.

Now, delete the cookie. If you reload the tab, you should get an error because you aren't logged in anymore.

What fails is the following:

You should be logged in, when clicking on the login button. This means, you first click the button. Then, open a new tab an go to the newsletter again you just were.

As you see, the login via ajax doesn't work. Why? I really couldn't figure out why it does set my cookie with a normal post but it doesn't when doing an ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make both application's session handler user the same domain. So if you have app1.foo.bar.com and app2.foo.bar.com you should be doing something like this in both of your apps:

```
Zend_Session::setOptions(array(
    'cookie_domain' => '.foo.bar.com'
));
```

One place for this code is the Bootstrap, but anywhere before you call `Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()` or start the session should be ok.

Comment: Just one Application is Zend based. But why does both application need it? App1 never cares about it. App1 makes a request to App2 which should respond a cookie which my browser sets so if i open a new window and go to App2, i should be logged in. Idk why my browser doesn't set the cookie. The respond cookie from app2 already got a domain set like that

Comment: I've now solved it with the forms target=iframe functionality.